# How do I add different packages to MAAS clients on installation?

Tags: server, maas

I would like to modify the images that are included in MAAS so that I can install laptops and desktops with it instead of the normal cloud images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert on this but it appears that you can configure the preseed to add late_commands. For example, you can configure the preseed to install a package based on the hostname, and after the installation has been completed:

```
late_commands:
{{if node.hostname == 'node01'}}
    package_install: ["curtin", "in-target", "--", "apt-get", "-y", "install", "mysql"]
{{endif}}
```

Note the following:

**Warning**

Do not try to alter the preseed files if you don’t have a good understanding of what you are doing. Altering the installed version of Ubuntu can prevent MAAS from working as intended, and may have security and stability consequences.

Source: https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html#altering-the-preseed-file

Further reading:

http://maas.io/docs/en/installconfig-images-mirror

http://maas.io/docs/en/manage-cli-images#select-images

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/var/lib/cobbler/snippets/mass_client_packages`

Add whatever package you need in a the same format as a debian preseed file, here is the default:

```
d-i pkgsel/include string cloud-init openssh-server python-software-properties vim avahi-daemon server^
```

You can add packages you want in there, or you can then customise this to do something like the desktop instead:

```
d-i pkgsel/include string ubuntu-desktop
```

This will install your packages on all subsequent installations (previously provisioned machines will be unaffected).

Comment: Say I want to make my MAAS server a local package repository as well... is it possible to configure MAAS to use the local package repository when packages are installed on subsequent installations?

Comment: Also, is it possible to specify different sets of packages for different types of machines? Or is this getting into Juju territory?

Comment: I think cobbler is no longer being used. At least the mentioned path does not exist anymore.